# Copy file with os.system

Tags: python-3.x, copy

I have several files named as follow `a_b.nc` `a_c.nc` `a_d.nc`.
I would like to copy/rename those files using a loop.

I tried using the following code:

```
import os
stations = ["b" , "c" , "d"]
inbasedir = "/home/david/test_pals/PALS/sites_lai/"
varname = "a_"
for station in stations:
    os.chdir(inbasedir)
    os.system("cp ${varname}${station}.nc ${varname}${station}_lai.nc")
```

The code produces no error, but at the same time it produces no output at all :)

Does anyone has an idea about how to produce the desired output?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting ?

Comment: I am not getting any error. It just not copy the file, in fact it does not produce anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone has an idea about how to produce the desired output?

You have to modify your string's syntax from`${varname}${station}` to something like this: `os.system("cp {0}{1}.nc ${0}${1}_lai.nc".format(varname, station))` and that would work. I would have done it this way:

```
import os
rename = ['f1.txt', 'f2.txt'] # list of files to rename
cur_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) # the dir with files
files = os.listdir() # list of all files in directory 

for f in files:
    if f in rename:
        os.popen("cp {0} {1}".format(f, f + "_renamed"))
```

In my present directory I have created these files `f1.txt` and `f2.txt`. After your run `os.popen("cp {0} {1}".format(f, f + "_renamed"))` I've got all files from the `rename` list changed.

**Remark:** Here is a description of [popen](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) and what is does.